# Can some one correct my code?

Tags: soql, opportunity

I want to throw an error when there is no 'Sow and GPE' attachments in an opportunity

```
List<String> reqDoc = new List<String>{'%sow%','%gpe%'};

for(Attachment attachment : [SELECT ParentId FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId = :Trigger.NewMap.keySet() AND Name in :reqDoc]) {
    system.debug('Attachment >> ' +attachment);
    if(attachment.Name.contains('sow'))
        SOWSet.add(attachment.ParentId);
    if(attachment.Name.contains('gpe'))
        GPESet.add(attachment.ParentId);
}
```

Comment: SELECT ParentId,name FROM Attachment, soql for name also before use it in attachment.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. What exactly is your problem and where are you stuck? Just posting a block of code won't really help. In order to help you we need more information, than just a piece of code. Also, it's a good idea to show what have you already tried and not just wait for us to write code for you

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please add more description to your question so that we can help you better. looking at your code for now I can suggest following

Update SOQL query by adding Name field and if you want to Ignore casing then you can use containsIgnoreCase for comparision.
Ref: [String Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm)

> ```
> containsIgnoreCase(substring)
> ```
>
> Returns true if the current String contains the specified sequence of 
>   characters without regard to case; otherwise, returns false.

```
for(Attachment attachment : [SELECT ParentId,Name FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId = :Trigger.NewMap.keySet() AND Name in :reqDoc]) {
    //Do Something and if possible use ContainsIngnoreCase For Comparison.
}
```

For displaying error message you can use `addError` method like

```
objectInstance.addError('Your Error Message');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to check if any Opportunities are missing either record, I'd recommend storing a Map of each Opportunity's attachments and then working from that.

```
List<String> reqDoc = new List<String>{'%sow%','%gpe%'};
Map<Opportunity, List<Attachment>> attachments = new Map<Opportunity, List<Attachment>>();
for(Attachment attachment : [SELECT ParentId FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId = :Trigger.NewMap.keySet() AND Name in :reqDoc]) {
    if(!attachments.containsKey(attachment.ParentID)){
        attachments.put(attachment.ParentID, new List<Attachment>());
    }
    attachments.get(attachment.ParentID).add(attachment);
}

for(Opportunity parent : Trigger.New){
    Attachment sow = null, gpe = null;
    if(attachments.containsKey(parent.ID)){
        for(Attachment attachment : attachments.get(parent.ID)){
            if(attachment.Name.contains('sow')){
                sow = attachment;
            }
            if(attachment.Name.contains('gpe')){
                gpe = attachment;
            }
        }
    }
    if(sow == null || gpe == null){
        if(sow == null){
            parent.addError('No SOW found');
        }
        if(gpe == null){
            parent.addError('No GPE found');
        }
    }
    else{
        SOWSet.add(sow);
        GPESet.add(gpe);
    }
}
```

If you want to be able to add new required documents just by adding them to the `reqDoc` list, you could use a `Map<String, Attachment>` instead of variables in the second loop and populate it with the strings in `reqDoc`.